# custom attributes in a script tag

Tags: javascript, html

Can I use a custom attribute in a `script` tag such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" mycustomattribute="foo">
    // JavaScript
</script>
```

And then use the contained JavaScript to access the value of `mycustomattribute`?

Comment: I've answered your question, but *why* do you want to do this? If we know why, we may be able to suggest a better option.

Comment: Side note: There's no reason to have the `type` attribute if the type is `text/javascript`, it's just wasted bandwidth. [That's the default](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type), universally.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. I am writing an "embed this wine review" widget. Currently I'm using an iframe, but I want something that can flow with the user's site layout better. So I'm using javascript to write the code into the page instead. But I need a reliable way to have the unique id of the user's wine review available to the javascript. (e.g. [link]http://www.napawapa.com/reviews/view/Yp/2006-Opus-One[/link]

Comment: If you need the attribute in order to have a unique id, why don’t you just use the `id` attribute?

Comment: Just a clarification: not a unique DOM element id, a unique wine id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Browsers are required to ignore attributes they don't recognize in any tag (to allow for graceful degradation when a document uses new features with an old browser).
However, it would be better to use a dataset tag, since these are explicitly reserved for users, so they don't conflict with future HTML changes.

```
<script id="myscript" type="text/javascript" data-mycustomattribute="foo">
```

You can then access this either using an ordinary attribute accessor:

```
document.getElementById("myscript").getAttribute("mycustomattribute")
```

or with the [`dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
document.getElementById("myscript").dataset.mycustomattribute
```

(but see the browser compatibility table in the documentation).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (how to access the attribute in JS).

Comment: @DannyBeckett He asked "if", not "how". I assumed he already knew how, and just wanted to know if there was any restriction on doing this with script tags.

Comment: An example would be nice to represent your answer.

Comment: @RodrigoRubio Done. Also added a documentation link.

Answer (score 11):

> Can I use a custom attribute in a script tag such as:

Yes, using [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes):

```
<script data-info="the information"...
```

> And then use the contained javascript to access the value of 'mycustomattribute'?

Yes, probably. If you give the `script` tag an `id`, you can do it reliably:

```
var info = document.getElementById("theId").getAttribute("data-info");
```

Otherwise, you have to make assumptions about the script tag. If it's always in the markup of the page (not added later using code), you can do this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var info = scripts[scripts.length - 1].getAttribute("data-info");
```

That's because if the script tag is in the markup, it's run as soon as it's encountered (unless [`async` or `defer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-async) is used [and supported by the browser]), and will always be the last script tag on the page (at that point in time). But again, if code adds the script tag *later*, using `createElement` and `appendChild` or similar, you can't rely on that.

Here's a complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/oxojol/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Data on Script Tags</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  </script>
  <script data-info="first">
    (function() {
      var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
      var info = scripts[scripts.length - 1].getAttribute("data-info");
      display("Got info '" + info + "'");
    })();
  </script>
  <script data-info="second">
    (function() {
      var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
      var info = scripts[scripts.length - 1].getAttribute("data-info");
      display("Got info '" + info + "'");
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Among the assumptions that must be made when getting the "last" script, is this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409982/is-it-the-last-script-element-the-currently-running-script#14410368

Comment: @Alohci: Good link. One of the large number of reasons why I prefer not to litter script tags all over the place, and certainly never nested within content (other than just before the closing `</body>` tag). I know that's what some people like to do, including some people you pretty much have to respect (Google Closure Library engineers, for instance), but it leads to that kind of thing...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it using jquery

```
$("script").attr("mycustomattribute");
```

Or try this using regular JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].getAttribute("mycustomattribute");
```

Might bake sense to give a script tag an id to be able to do this

```
document.getElementById("someId").getAttribute("mycustomattribute");
```

Comment: Yes, true, but this is going to be a script block embedded on external sites where there is no guarantee of jquery existing. :(

Comment: That's a workable solution as well. Thanks for the additional approach!

Answer (score 0):

I built a [library](https://github.com/FarhadG/script-tag-data) for this very instance and it's quite easy to use:

```
<script id="your-library" src="./your-library.js" data-car="pagani" data-star-repo="yes, please :)">
```

and then you can get that data:

```
/**
 * This returns the following:
 *
 * {
 *   car: 'pagani',
 *   starRepo: 'yes, please :)'
 * }
 */

 ScriptTagData.getData('your-library');


 /**
  * This returns the juust <script> tag
  */

 ScriptTagData.getData('your-library');
```

You can download it via Bower, CDN or just take the code: https://github.com/FarhadG/script-tag-data

Comment: Please do review [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085) before posting your library to more questions.