# Dynamically load javascript file with a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to replace this line of HTML with some javascript code that will dynamically load the script, and provide a callback once the script is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="SOME VALUE HERE"></script>
```

I can use jquery's `$.ajax()` function to load the file, but how do I set the `data-app-key` value?

```
$.ajax({
    dataType : 'script',
    cache    : true,
    url      : 'https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js',
    complete : onApiLoad,
});
```

Comment: Create a hidden element (can be a span or a form element doesn't matter) with given id (dropboxjs) and set that data-app-key attribute on this element. JS file, that you are including is just trying to read the data- attribute of an element with given id. Try  `<span id="dropboxjs" style="display: none" data-app-key="some value here"> `

Comment: Refer to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769688/custom-attributes-in-a-script-tag

Comment: pasted my comment as an answer so that you can mark it answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hidden element (can be a span or a form element doesn't matter) with given id (dropboxjs) and set that data-app-key attribute on this element. JS file, that you are including is just trying to read the data- attribute of an element with given id. Try