# How to check the attribute value of the script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm letting people include my JS script like

```
<script src='example.js' test='1'></script>
```

So my question is, how would i check if test is equal to 1 or 0 inside the script which it is loading?

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `alert(document.currentScript.getAttribute("test"))`

Comment: Before it loads the script, i want it to check if the script has the value of 1 or 0, this is ment to be done in pure JS!

Comment: you can point to it from another script. the easy way is to give the script tag an _id_. however, i'm not sure if you can see tags that have not executed yet. to wit: `document.getElementByTagName("script")` always returns a collection where the _document.currentScript_ is in the last position (w/o _defer_ being in play)

Comment: you can see the pages:


[DEMO][1]

[DEMO 1][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769688/custom-attributes-in-a-script-tag
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904378/get-data-attribute-of-script-tag

Comment: Are you sure the `test` attribute is retained in all browsers after parsing? It's not a standard attribute, and browsers have no obligation to keep stuff like that in memory. Different browsers react differently to errors, remember that! Why don't you play it safe and use a proper attribute like `data-test` or something.