# <script src=...> to output to specified div

Tags: javascript, html, src

I have some external code (I can't modify) to pull an RSS feed using https://rss.bloople.net/.

The JS code from this site is provided as in this example:

```
<script src="//rss.bloople.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.feedforall.com%2Fsample.xml&detail=-1&showtitle=false&type=js"></script>
```

I am trying to place this into a long accordion list with the relevant RSS feed displaying when each accordion is expanded.

If I hard code this in the load time is very long, so I want to dynamically call the script. However, when I have achieved this, the output of the code is placed at the end of the page rather than inside the accordion panel.

I would prefer not to use an iframe solution, as the height of the feed is variable, but I will consider all options of course.

I have tried using onclick, loading the script through `script = document.createElement("script");`

then appending this to a div using append.child

This appears to work, but I guess what it is doing is loading the script here then executing it. but executing it adds the output text to the end of the document.

I guess what I need it so store the output as a variable and append the div with the variable rather than the script...?

Example code below - accordion not working fully, but I can fix this later...

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css' integrity='sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ' crossorigin='anonymous'>
<style>
type="text/css">a {text-decoration: none}
.accordion {
    background-color: #470a68;
    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid;
border-color: white;
border-width:1px;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #0092bc; 
}

.accordion2 {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: #280071;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: none;
border-color: grey;
border-width:1px;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.active2, .accordion2:hover {
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
    border-bottom-style: solid #ddd;
}

.accordion3 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #280071;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: none;
border-color: grey;
border-width:1px;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.active3, .accordion3:hover {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border-bottom-style: solid #ddd;
}


.panel {
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: white;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-color: grey;
border-width:1px;
}
 .row { vertical-align: top; height:auto !important;}
 .list {display:none; }
 .show {display: none; }
 .hide:target + .show {display: inline; }
 .hide:target {display: none; }
 .hide:target ~ .list {display:inline; }
 @media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;

}

th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {background-color:#e0e0e0;}


}

.container {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
height: 200;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 50%;
height: 200%;
}

.resp-container {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 56.25%;
}
.resp-iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 0;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="accordion">Topic 1</button><div class="panel">                     <button id="LoadRSS1" class="accordion2"><b>Load Topic 1 RSS</b></button>
<button class="accordion3"><b>RSS to load under here</b><br>

<script type="text/javascript">

LoadRSS1.onclick = function(){

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "//rss.bloople.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.feedforall.com%2Fsample.xml&detail=-1&limit=5&showtitle=false&type=js"; 
   document.getElementById("RSSHere").appendChild(script);
    return false;
}
</script>

<div id="RSSHere"></div>

</button>            
            </div>  

<button class="accordion">Topic 2</button><div class="panel">                     <button id="LoadRSS2" class="accordion2"><b>Load Topic 2 RSS</b></button>
<button class="accordion3"><b>RSS to load under here</b><br>
   <script type="text/javascript">

LoadRSS2.onclick = function(){

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "//rss.bloople.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.feedforall.com%2Fsample.xml&detail=-1&limit=5&showtitle=false&type=js"; 
   document.getElementById("RSSHere2").appendChild(script);
    return false;
}
</script>

<div id="RSSHere2"></div>

</div>



<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
var acc2 = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion2");
var ii;

for (ii = 0; ii < acc2.length; ii++) {
    acc2[ii].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active2");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
function scrollFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("PGframe");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function stopEventPropogation(e){
e.stopPropogation()
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//////////////////////////
$( '#accordion' ).accordion({
animate: 1000,
beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
$('#d1').html("newHeader : " + ui.newHeader.text() + " <br> newPanel : " + ui.newPanel.text() )
$('#d1').append(" <br><br> oldHeader : " + ui.oldHeader.text() + "<br> oldPanel : " + ui.oldPanel.text());
 }
});
/////////////////
})

</script>
```

one odd observation is that if I keep clicking the accordion button to load the script it eventually starts loading in the correct place. I've no idea why this would be.

Answer (score 2):

The script uses the following code to insert its DOM nodes.

```
var script = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1];
var parent = script.parentNode;
while(nodes.length > 0) parent.insertBefore(nodes.shift(), script);
parent.removeChild(script);
```

The first line sets `script` to the last `<script>` tag on the page, and this will be the tag that loads this script during page loading. It then inserts the DOM nodes before the script and finally removes the script.

This is basically a modern version of the traditional use of `document.write()` to insert HTML code where the script is located.

If you insert the script tag in the middle of the document sometime later, it won't necessarily be the last script in the page, so it won't insert the HTML in the desired place.

There isn't really anything you can do about this, it's just not designed to be used the way you want. If you have a business relationship with the site, you could suggest that they provide better ways to customize it, such as a URL parameter that allows you to specify the ID of the DOM element where the new elements should be inserted.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the information. 

Do you have any other suggested approaches to achieve this that I could try? 

An alternative option is to use the iFrame code they also provide:

`<iframe src="//rss.bloople.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.feedforall.com%2Fsample.xml&detail=-1&limit=5&showtitle=false&type=html"></iframe>

Comment: It's not really the "modern" way. The modern way would be to use document.currentScript  (no IE support though) because [using the last script in the DOM can be prone to unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409982/is-it-the-last-script-element-the-currently-running-script#14410368)

Comment: @Alohci OK, it's more modern than the old way.

Comment: @AlexHarrison If that's what they recommend, go with it.